# Running webpack output in browser complains 'require' is not defined

Tags: webpack, require

I have a small app I'm trying to output for node and another version for the web. I also have a separate config for each. My browser console has this error after running it through webpack:

```
external_"lodash":1 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at eval (external_"lodash":1)
    at Object.lodash (browser.js:507)
    at __webpack_require__ (browser.js:20)
    at eval (page.js:1)
    at Object../src/page.js (browser.js:429)
    at __webpack_require__ (browser.js:20)
    at eval (write-template.js:2)
    at Object../src/write-template.js (browser.js:474)
    at __webpack_require__ (browser.js:20)
    at eval (browser.js:2)
    at Object../src/browser.js (browser.js:319)
    at __webpack_require__ (browser.js:20)
    at eval (browser.js:1)
    at Object.0 (browser.js:485)
    at __webpack_require__ (browser.js:20)
    at browser.js:69
    at browser.js:72
```

---

```
/***/ "lodash":
/*!*************************!*\
  !*** external "lodash" ***!
  \*************************/
/*! no static exports found */
/***/ (function(module, exports) {

eval("module.exports = require(\"lodash\");\n\n//# sourceURL=webpack:///external_%22lodash%22?");

/***/ }),
```

I thought webpack would fix require(). Here's the config for my webpack:

```
{
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.hbs/,
        loader: 'handlebars-template-loader',
        query: {
          noEscape: true
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: __dirname,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      src: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/'),
      elements: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/elements/')
    }
  },
  entry: ['./src/browser.js'],
  target: 'web',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '../') + '/output',
    filename: 'browser.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, '../') + '/output',
  }
}
```

Did I configure something the wrong way?

Comment: did you figure it out ?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem with how you’ve defined [the `externals` property](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/), which tells Webpack about certain dependencies that should be excluded from your built application bundle. By default, the source code for all dependencies (i.e. `node_modules`) is bundled with your application.

The syntax for the `externals` property is typically an object that maps your externalized dependencies to information about where to find those dependencies at runtime. In most cases, this information is a string pointing to a global variable where your dependency can be found at runtime. So, for example, the following configuration removes `lodash` from your application bundle and tells Webpack that `lodash` can be found at runtime as the global variable `'_'`:

```
{
  externals: {
    lodash: '_'
  }
}
```

When externals is defined as an array, as you have done here, the output of your externalized dependency in your application bundle is simply a `require` statement. This can work fine in a Node environment where `require` is a known function for resolving modules, but it doesn’t work in a browser environment where there is no definition of `require`. That explains the error you’re seeing in your browser console. Since you say your app is small, for simplicity I would recommend getting rid of the `externals` configuration entirely for your web bundle. Otherwise, use the object syntax to configure `externals`.